# Set cell value to NaN under certain conditions using lambda map in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, nan

I'm trying to change the value of certain cells in a particular column to NaN if the current value of the cell does not meet certain conditions.

In particular, I have a column of prices. df['prices']. The values in this column look like this: [23, 34, 36/375, NA, 62]. I'd like to do a check to see if the value in a certain row of that column is a digit and, if it isn't, change the value to NaN. So, the resulting column vector would be [23, 34, NaN, NaN, 62].

I've tried to make an iterative approach but it's far too slow / may not be working at all. Using lambda and map is very fast in Pandas but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) here:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[23], [34], ['36/375'], ['NA'], [62]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
        0
0      23
1      34
2  36/375
3      NA
4      62

In [13]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[13]:
    0
0  23
1  34
2 NaN
3 NaN
4  62
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy's solution works well. However, the method `convert_objects` is now deprecated and has been removed in version `0.18`.

Instead use `pandas.to_numeric()` with the parameter `errors='coerce'` :

```
columns = [list of clumns to change]

for col in columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```